# Copying files from SMB server to local drive(Linux/Windows) in python

Tags: python

I am using smb module to connect to smb server. I am unable to figure out what exactly I could do to copy files from smb to my local drive as I am using linux machine.

```
import tempfile
from smb.SMBConnection import SMBConnection
from nmb.NetBIOS import NetBIOS

conn = SMBConnection('salead', 
                     'repo@2k12', 
                     '192.168.14.1', 
                     'SERVER', 
                     use_ntlm_v2=True)
assert conn.connect('192.168.1.41', 139)
if conn:
    print "successfull",conn
else:
    print "failed to connect"
```

If anyone can help me out it would be a great help for me. Thanks

Answer (score 13):

According to [some documentation](http://pysmb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/smb_SMBConnection.html), `SMBConnection.retrieveFile()` is the function you are searching for.

Example:

```
# UNTESTED
conn = SMBConnection('salead',
                     'repo@2k12',
                     '192.168.14.1',
                     'SERVER',
                     use_ntlm_v2 = True)
assert conn.connect('192.168.1.41', 139)
with open('local_file', 'wb') as fp:
    conn.retrieveFile('share', '/path/to/remote_file', fp)
```

Documentation: http://pysmb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/smb_SMBConnection.html

Example (in Japanese): http://symfoware.blog68.fc2.com/blog-entry-999.html

Comment: Two of these links are broken.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - Thanks.

Comment: important: the save mode must be wb.

Answer (score 5):

The documentation referenced above by @Rob should get you there. Here is an idea that works using an abstracted class:

```sh
> pip install pysmb
```

```py
import subprocess

from smb import SMBConnection


class SMBClient:
    def __init__(self, ip, username, password, servername, share_name):
        self._ip = ip
        self._username = username
        self._password = password
        self._port = 445
        self._share_name = share_name
        self._servername = servername
        self._server = ''

    def _connect(self):
        """ Connect and authenticate to the SMB share. """
        self._server = SMBConnection(username=self._username,
                                    password=self._password,
                                    my_name=self._get_localhost(),
                                    remote_name=self._servername,
                                    use_ntlm_v2=True)
        self._server.connect(self._ip, port=self._port)

    def _download(self, files: list):
        """ Download files from the remote share. """
        for file in files:
            with open(file, 'wb') as file_obj:
                self._server.retrieveFile(service_name=self._share_name,
                                          path=file,
                                          file_obj=file_obj)

    def _get_localhost(self):
        self._host = subprocess.Popen(['hostname'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].strip()
```

Then, all you need to do is this:

```py
filename = [the file you want to download]
smb_client = SMBClient(ip='192.168.14.1', username='salead', password='repo@2k12', servername='SERVER', share_name='SHARE_NAME')
smb_client._connect()
response = smb_client._download(filename)
```

Main Documentation: https://pysmb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html
SMBConnection Documentation: https://pysmb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/smb_SMBConnection.html

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was necessary to copy files from one remote machine to another remote machine. Both remote machines are managed by Windows OS

```py
import tempfile

from smb.SMBConnection import SMBConnection

client_machine_name = 'mylocalmachinename'

# first domen settings
userID_1 = 'admin_1'
password_1 = '123'
server_name_1 = 'SERVER_1'
server_ip_1 = '192.168.1.1'
# path to remote file in windows format we want to read 
# "D:\myfiles\dir\somefile.txt". In this case, full access
# to disk d is open. But if you have published only a separate
# catalog, in our example "myfiles", then:
# share_resource_1 = 'myfiles'
# path_to_file_1 = '/dir/somefile.txt'
share_resource_1 = 'd'
path_to_file_1 = '/myfiles/dir/somefile.txt'

# second domen settings
userID_2 = 'admin_2'
password_2 = '123'
server_name_2 = 'SERVER_2'
server_ip_2 = '192.168.1.2'
# path to remote file we want to save in windows format "D:\myfiles\dir\somefile_copy.txt"
share_resource_2 = 'd'
path_to_file_2 = '/myfiles/dir/somefile_copy.txt'


conn_1 = SMBConnection(
    userID_1, password_1, client_machine_name, server_name_1, use_ntlm_v2 = True
)
conn_2 = SMBConnection(
    userID_2, password_2, client_machine_name, server_name_2, use_ntlm_v2 = True
)
conn_1.connect(server_ip_1, 139)
conn_2.connect(server_ip_2, 139)


with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as file_obj:
    conn_1.retrieveFile(share_resource_1, path_to_file_1, file_obj)
    # Note that the file obj is positioned at the end-of-file,
    # so you might need to perform a file_obj.seek() if you need
    # to read from the beginning
    file_obj.seek(0)
    conn_2.storeFile(share_resource_2, path_to_file_2, file_obj)
```